# php short_open_tag problem

Tags: php

hi i am working on a project of my college but my college server admin told me that we don’t use short_open_tag in our code what’s its mean? what is short open tag and what is alternate of it

thanks

Comment: You didn't ask but the main reason to avoid using short open tags is that your code will be more portable (because it may have to be run on a server that doesn't allow short tags) and it makes writing XML documents easier (short open tags would require a call to echo, i.e., `echo "<?xml"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you write PHP like so: `<?php PHP CODE HERE ?>`. However if *allow_short_tags* directive is enabled you're able to use: `<? PHP CODE HERE ?>`. Also sort tags provides extra syntax: `<?= $var ?>` which is equal to `<?php echo $var ?>`.

Short tags might seem cool but they're not. They causes only more problems. Oh... and IIRC they'll be removed from PHP6.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the tool at:

http://blog.eezgu.com/php-short-open-tag-sorunu-ve-cozumu.html

This is a PHP command line tool that converts short tags to normal PHP tags.

The page is not English but you can click the link in the post and download the tool.