# If else embedding inside html

Tags: php, html

What is the correct way of embedding if else  and elseif conditions inside html?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the opposite?

Answer (score 203):

I recommend the following syntax for readability.

```
<? if ($condition): ?>
  <p>Content</p>
<? elseif ($other_condition): ?>
  <p>Other Content</p>
<? else: ?>
  <p>Default Content</p>
<? endif; ?>
```

Note, omitting `php` on the open tags does require that `short_open_tags` is enabled in your configuration, [which is the default](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). The relevant curly-brace-free conditional syntax is always enabled and can be used regardless of this directive.

Comment: This example is missing the 'PHP' in the statements.

Comment: @AdamYoungers These are called short_open_tags, and while you might not be familiar with them, they're perfectly valid.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with them. I tried using the above and it broke my page.  A quick search and I see you have to enable this in your php.ini file... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: do not provide examples that assume special configurations. Assume default config. Please correct your answer to include the PHP in the tag. You can include how to setup this configuration and then show the difference but that is beyond the scope of the question. Other than that your answer is valid.

Comment: I would highly suggest not using php short tags. It can add confusion, and as well cause random errors that can lead to developers pulling out their hair.

Comment: @NateAGeek You are welcome to not use them, but opining on a 5 year old answer is unnecessary.

Answer (score 54):

```
<?php if ($foo) { ?>
    <div class="mydiv">Condition is true</div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="myotherdiv">Condition is false</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 25):

In @Patrick McMahon's response, the second comment here ( ***$first_condition is false** and $second_condition is true* ) is not entirely accurate:

```
<?php if($first_condition): ?>
  /*$first_condition is true*/
  <div class="first-condition-true">First Condition is true</div>
<?php elseif($second_condition): ?>
  /*$first_condition is false and $second_condition is true*/
  <div class="second-condition-true">Second Condition is true</div>
<?php else: ?>
  /*$first_condition and $second_condition are false*/
  <div class="first-and-second-condition-false">Conditions are false</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Elseif** fires whether **$first_condition** is true or false, as do additional **elseif** statements, if there are multiple.

I am no PHP expert, so I don't know whether that's the *correct* way to say **IF this OR that ELSE that** or if there is another/better way to code it in PHP, but this would be an important distinction to those looking for OR conditions versus ELSE conditions.

Source is [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp) and my own experience.

Comment: Are you sure? Just tested it with: `if(true){ echo 'here';} elseif (true){ echo 'second';} else { echo 'whaddup';}exit;` Output: "here" On PHP 5.5

Answer (score 6):

You will find multiple different methods that people use and they each have there own place.

```
<?php if($first_condition): ?>
  /*$first_condition is true*/
<?php elseif ($second_condition): ?>
  /*$first_condition is false and $second_condition is true*/
<?php else: ?>
  /*$first_condition and $second_condition are false*/
<?php endif; ?>
```

If in your php.ini attribute `short_open_tag = true` (this is normally found on `line 141` of the default php.ini file) you can replace your php open tag from `<?php` to `<?`. **This is not advised** as most live server environments have this turned off (including many CMS's like Drupal, WordPress and Joomla). I have already tested short hand open tags in Drupal and confirmed that it will break your site, so stick with `<?php`. `short_open_tag` is not on by default in all server configurations and must not be assumed as such when developing for unknown server configurations. Many hosting companies have `short_open_tag` turned off.

A quick search of `short_open_tag` in stackExchange shows 830 results. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=short_open_tag
That's a lot of people having problems with something they should just not play with.

*with some server environments and applications, short hand php open tags will still crash your code even with `short_open_tag` set to `true`.*

**`short_open_tag` will be removed in PHP6 so don't use short hand tags.**

all future PHP versions will be dropping `short_open_tag`

- http://www.askapache.com/php/shorthand-short_open_tag.html
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

> "It's been recommended for several years that you not use the short
>   tag "short cut" and instead to use the full  tag
>   combination. With the wide spread use of XML and use of these tags by
>   other languages, the server can become easily confused and end up
>   parsing the wrong code in the wrong context. But because this short
>   cut has been a feature for such a long time, it's currently still
>   supported for backwards compatibility, but we recommend you don't use
>   them." –  Jelmer Sep 25 '12 at 9:00 
>   [php: "short_open_tag = On" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579448/php-short-open-tag-on-not-working)

and

> Normally you write PHP like so: . However if
>   *allow_short_tags* directive is enabled you're able to use: . Also sort tags provides extra syntax:  which
>   is equal to .
>
> Short tags might seem cool but they're not. They causes only more
>   problems. Oh... and IIRC they'll be removed from PHP6.
>   Crozin answered Aug 24 '10 at 22:12
>   [php short_open_tag problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561423/php-short-open-tag-problem)

and

> To answer the why part, I'd quote Zend PHP 5 certification guide:
>   "Short tags were, for a time, the standard in the PHP world; however,
>   they do have the major drawback of conflicting with XML headers and,
>   therefore, have somewhat fallen by the wayside." –  Fluffy Apr 13 '11
>   at 14:40
>   [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

You may also see people use the following example:

```
<?php if($first_condition){ ?>
  /*$first_condition is true*/
<?php }else if ($second_condition){ ?>
  /*$first_condition is false and $second_condition is true*/
<?php }else{ ?>
  /*$first_condition and $second_condition are false*/
<?php } ?>
```

This will work but it is highly frowned upon as it's not considered as legible and is not what you would use this format for. If you had a PHP file where you had a block of PHP code that didn't have embedded tags inside, then you would use the bracket format.

The following example shows when to use the bracket method

```
<?php
if($first_condition){
   /*$first_condition is true*/
}else if ($second_condition){
   /*$first_condition is false and $second_condition is true*/
}else{
   /*$first_condition and $second_condition are false*/
}
?>
```

If you're doing this code for yourself you can do what you like, but if your working with a team at a job it is advised to use the correct format for the correct circumstance. If you use brackets in embedded html/php scripts that is a good way to get fired, as no one will want to clean up your code after you. IT bosses will care about code legibility and college professors grade on legibility.

**UPDATE**

based on comments from duskwuff its still unclear if shorthand is discouraged (by the php standards) or not. I'll update this answer as I get more information. But based on many documents found on the web about shorthand being bad for portability. I would still personally not use it as it gives no advantage and you must rely on a setting being on that is not on for every web host.

Comment: "in PHP6"? PHP 6 doesn't exist, and never will. The next major version is PHP 7, and is not expected to change the status of short_open_tags.

Comment: @duskwuff It's possible you may be correct about them jumping to PHP7 and skipping PHP6. but they are considering  short_open_tags as discouraged in PHP5 and will be deprecated.

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that they are "discouraged", or "will be deprecated"? The documentation says absolutely nothing to suggest this. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: @duskwuff I'm merely referencing documents others have stated. see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554753/php-5-5-short-open-tag-on-security-hole and for what i have said about portability and how you can't assume every server has it turned on, I'm not incorrect and how everyone on the web is saying not to use short hand I have to side with the numbers provided. There is simply to many people saying not to use them rather then using them. along with no advantage for using them.

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon You haven't provided any numbers. You're linking to a single StackOverflow answer that's hardly an authority, and expanding it to “everyone on the web”. Get a grip.

Comment: @coreyward given your exceptional persuasion skills. I'm having doubt about my original stance on the php standards being discouraged. looking back on my references it looks more like people are discouraging it not the php folks. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?php if (date("H") < "12" && date("H")>"6") { ?>
   src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/img/morning.gif" 
 <?php } elseif (date("H") > "12" && date("H")<"17") { ?>
 src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/img/noon.gif" 
  <?php } elseif (date("H") > "17" && date("H")<"21") { ?>
   src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/img/evening.gif" 
  <?php } elseif (date("H") > "21" && date("H")<"24") { ?>
  src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/img/night.gif" 
  <?php }else { ?>
  src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/img/mid_night.gif" 
  <?php } ?>
```