# php: "short_open_tag = On" not working

Tags: php

I have recently installed Win8 on my computer. Then I instaled wamp 2.2 with php 5.4 and I am unable to make short tag work.

I have already put:

> "short_open_tag = On"

into the php.ini file and I am sure that apache is loading the right file because the path to "Loaded Configuration File" in `phpinfo()` is good.

I would be glad for any piece of advice. Thanks.

Comment: Did you restart WAMP after making the change to your php.ini file?

Comment: WARNING! did you read the comment above the short_open_tag? -> "It's been recommended for several years that you not use the short tag "short cut" and instead to use the full <?php and ?> tag combination. With the wide spread use of XML and use of these tags by other languages, the server can become easily confused and end up parsing the wrong code in the wrong context. But because this short cut has been a feature for such a long time, it's currently still supported for backwards compatibility, but we recommend you don't use them."

Comment: `<?=$someVar; ?>` (as replace for `<?php echo`) should work regardless of the setting `short_open_tag` in PHP 5.4. Anything other you want to do with short tags isn't recommended, **strongly!**

Comment: @DanLee a lot of people are still using 5.3 and lower. But yes, **don't** use the short opening tags.

Comment: @DainisAbols I am referring to his question: `Then I instaled wamp 2.2 with php 5.4`

Comment: Same issue with xampp. It's the `php.ini` file. `short_open_tag = Off` below the `short_open_tag = On`.

Answer (score 54):

I had the same problem recently after upgrading from `PHP 5.3.18` to `PHP 5.5.9.`.

I realized that for some reason, `short_open_tag` was appearing in my php.ini file twice.

If you did a find to get to that part of your `php.ini` file, try continuing the find to see if there is another instance.

Comment: And thanks from me. I spent quite a lot of time on this pesky thing.

Comment: 4 hours wasted. And some hair. Thank you!

Comment: who wrote the default php.ini should die horribly right now.

Comment: You save my life bro

Answer (score 8):

Set the :

```
asp_tags = On and short_open_tag = On
```

in both the files \apache\Apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini and \bin\php\php5.4\php.ini and then restart the apache server.

If you don't have access to the php.ini you can try to enable them trough the .htaccess file but it's possible the hosting company disabled this if you are on shared hosting:

```
php_value short_open_tag 1
```

Remember to restart your service (apache2, etc) for the edits to php.ini to take effect.

Comment: I restarted apache, that wasn't a problem I also added aspt_tags but still not working.. So i replaced all the shorten tags and I will not use I guess

Comment: This solution only worked for me if I did the php_value short_open_tag 1 inside .htaccess.  Not sure why it wouldn't work in php.ini, it is showing on in phpinfo()  and I have restarted apache.  using PHP 5.4- maybe that's it?

Answer (score 7):

Change the value of `short_open_tag` to `On`.

And if your `php.ini` file is located in `/etc/php/5.6/fpm` you need to restart the `php5.6-fpm` service with

```
sudo service php5.6-fpm restart
```

Comment: In my case: **service php5-fpm restart**

Comment: Same for 7.4: sudo service php7.4-fpm restart

Comment: In my case I'm using Debian in GCP with php 8.1 and apache so `sudo systemctl restart php8.1-fpm` did work for me

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to replace all

```
short_open_tag
```

occurrences within the php.ini file.
In my case there were multiple places where it was defined.
For me, the wrong setting was located under

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Language Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Answer (score 0):

The two most common mistakes are changing the value inside the commented section (lines starting with `;` are not executed) and changing the *wrong* configuration.

In `/etc/php/VERSION/` you will find multiple folders, such as `cli`, `mods-available`, `apache`, etc. based on your server set up. For instance, if you want to change the config for the PHP module used by Apache, you should go to `/etc/php/VERSION/apache/php.ini`.

People often modify the config in the `cli` folder by mistake as multiple online tutorials suggest the command `php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"` to find your `php.ini` file, however, this command will often direct you to the cli config.

When using Apache, you will also have to run `sudo systemctl reload apache2` (for Debian-based distributions) to enable the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently after upgrading from PHP 5.4 to PHP 8.0

I realized that for i have to enable

```
short_open_tag = On
```

from the laragon as i am using the laragon in other case you can check your apache php.ini file.