# "<?= site_url('user/profile') ?>" not working on codeigniter 2.1.3

Tags: php

`"<?= site_url('user/profile') ?>"` not working on codeigniter 2.1.3

the problem its with

site_url not working on the server

```
<a href="<?= site_url('user/profile') ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url()." alt="profile"></a>
```

if i do it like this it works

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('user/profile') ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url()."alt="profile"></a>
```

on the localhost it works and in another server

maybe the server should have something installed on the php

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" exactly, what happens? Try removing the space between `=` and `site_url` though

Answer (score 1):

It seems your server's `php.ini` file has not enabled [`short_open_tag`s](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Answer (score 1):

You must have set `short_open_tag` to `on` in php.ini for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the server configuration. If you are saying that

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('user/profile') ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url()."alt="profile"></a>
```

works, it means `short_open_tag` directive is off in `php.ini` file, so you must always use the full tag `<?php`.

For extra info, check this old question. [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Comment: how to configure this

Comment: @AravinthE That's a different question :) I'd search here in Stack Overflow... I'd find results like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579448/php-short-open-tag-on-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that `<?php echo` works but `<?=` does not, it looks like Short Tags are disabled in your target environment's php.ini.

Please note that the use of short tags [is discouraged](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)