# PHP & Oracle database edit/update data

Tags: php, oracle

I'm using PHP in combination with an Oracle database. What I want is the following: On the first form I want to select a name out of a table in the database and when you push the button open I want the users to see a html form where the fields are filled in with the information from the person you've selected on the first screen. You can edit this information and when you push the update button the table has to be updated. I don't know who to do this whole process in PHP in combination with Oracle. Can someone please help me? This is an important part of a project I'm doing and I can't find any information anywhere!
I really hope someone can help me.
PHP & Oracle database edit/update data.
geting error `Undefined variable: objResult` on <<<-----here

```
<?
    $objConnect = oci_connect("myuser", "mypassword", "TCDB");
    $strSQL     = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER";
    $objParse   = oci_parse($objConnect, $strSQL);
    oci_execute($objParse, OCI_DEFAULT);
?>  
            <table width="600" border="1">  
            <tr>  
            <th width="91"> <div align="center">CustomerID  </div></th>  
            <th width="98"> <div align="center">Name  </div></th>  
            <th width="198"> <div align="center">Email  </div></th>  
            <th width="97"> <div align="center">CountryCode  </div></th>  
            <th width="59"> <div align="center">Budget  </div></th>  
            <th width="71"> <div align="center">Used  </div></th>  
            <th width="30"> <div align="center">Edit  </div></th>  
            </tr>  
<?
    while ($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_BOTH))
    {
?>  
             <tr>  
             <td><div  align="center"><?= $objResult["CUSTOMERID"]; ?></div></td>  <<---here
             <td><?= $objResult["NAME"]; ?></td>  <<---here
              <td><?= $objResult["EMAIL"]; ?></td>  <<---here
              <td><div  align="center"><?= $objResult["COUNTRYCODE"]; ?></div></td>  
                 <td align="right"><?= $objResult["BUDGET"]; ?></td>  <<---here
                    <td align="right"><?= $objResult["USED"]; ?></td>  

             <td align="center"><a  href="php_oracle_update2.php?CusID=                                                                                  <?=$objResult["CUSTOMERID"];?>">Edit</a></td>    
               </tr> 
               <?
                }
               ?> 
                </table>  
<?
    oci_close($objConnect);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error could mean that `short_open_tag` isn't enabled in your `php.ini`, and due to that PHP actually sees no code in your template. Only the `<?= ... ?>` tags are working, while the `<? ... ?>` are not.

Your options:

1. Set `short_open_tag = On` in your php.ini. Or,
2. use full `<?php ... ?>` tags instead

Also, the while loop isn't complete. Try:

```
<?
    while ($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_BOTH)):
?>  

    // ...

<?
    endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: i can't see  to set short_open_tag = On in php.ini plz help

Comment: You should be using <?php ... ?> it's best practice. Anyhow, just add the line at the bottom (anywhere) in php.ini, restart server. Maybe try this for troubleshoot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579448/php-short-open-tag-on-not-working Also check out http://php.net/short-open-tag

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop will probably only work for the first line. Make sure you use `{ }` for every loop, be it one line or many.