# PHP page displaying server side code

Tags: php, php-shorttags

My PHP site is configured on IIS and the page is showing server side code in browser for e.g.

```
<? some code here ?>
```

I suspect it is due to `<?` as opening tag instead of `<?php`

I have set **short_open_tag** to **On** in php.ini but still server side code is being displayed. What could be the reason? PHP version is 5.4

Comment: does your PHP code gets executed when you use `<?php` ?

Comment: Assuming the answer to TudorConstantin's question is 'yes', what does `var_dump(ini_get('short_open_tag'));` output? Make sure you're editing the correct php.ini file (`echo php_ini_loaded_file()`).

Comment: I used phpinfo() and it is showing short_open_tag as On.

Comment: and how did you make your phpinfo() to be executed and not displayed like a string? the file with the phpinfo contains short open tags or long ones?

Comment: @FrankMartin This help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579448/php-short-open-tag-on-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Once i had the same problem but i figure it out. There is two instances of short_open_tag. Look for both and make both of them on.

Comment: Why not just delete one?

Comment: It is by default there. I just upgraded and it was showing twice. I never go for to delete it instead i make it on. You can check if you have the same problem by deleting one of them.