# HTML inside an if statement php8

Tags: php

I have the following script.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>test</TITLE>
<body>
<?
$foo=1;
if($foo==0){
    echo '<div class="main_container">';

echo "no";

echo'</div>';
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

in php version 7.4 this outputs nothing.
In php8 it outputs
'; echo "no"; echo''; } ?>
If I remove the html and body tags it outputs nothing.
How can I get this if statement to work properly in php8 inside html and body tags?

I expected the script to output nothing in php8

Comment: See Item 5 on [the duplicate's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/19068).

Comment: Also relevant: [php: "short_open_tag = On" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74645250/2943403)