# PHP 5.5 short_open_tag=on Security Hole?

Tags: php, php-shorttags

I've upgraded to PHP5.5 and in the **PHP.ini** now `short_open_tag=off` and I recognized this because some files are now not running because `<?` instead of `<?php`.

Now there are two solutions scouting for any php file and change the open tag to `<?php` or activate `short_open_tag=on`

Is there any security problem with the second option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not a direct security vulnerability but it could become one given the proper conditions.

First off let's specs standards. In PHP 5.4 and higher the `short_open_tag=on` directive applies to all short tags except `<?=` - the echo tag. 
Generally it is considered that using short tags all over your code is a bad practice because of portability. I personally do now use short tags. 
Since PHP 5.4 and >= 5.4 the short echo tag `<?=` is always available and not affected by the `short_open_tag` ini directive. I consider this decision to separate the echo tag from the others a good one.

Actually the [PSR Standards](http://www.php-fig.org/) suggest this. So:
[PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) suggests to only use `<?php ?>` or `<?= ?>` (echo short tag) - **and no other variations**, and [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) suggests to not close the tags in PHP-only files. This may seem strange but sometimes there could be untraceable errors in your code because of a single space (' ') character just before your opening or just after your closing bracket. This is a well known issue. I adhere to both practices as I have seen it all go very wrong because of different tags usage in old projects.

**Where did this all begin?**

Back in the early days of PHP people started realizing that the PHP tags conflict with those of XML and ASP. Yes you can use `<% //code here %>` as a open/close tag.
Then it was decided that PHP would use `<?php ?>` as to distinguish itself from XML and ASP - kind of a top-level namespace for PHP code.
Actually the ASP tags were introduced as a comfortable way to ease adoption of PHP by ASP developers.

ASP tags are handled by the `asp_tags` ini directive and they should be off.

Again - the debate for the short tags was held and that is why now there is a separation between short tags and the short echo tag. I consider this a good thing. Just replace all short tags in your legacy code.

**Now about security**.

The only case you should worry about is when you have some user input that somehow ends up going through the PHP interpreter. You will need to strip:

- Normal PHP tags
- Short PHP tags
- Short Echo tags
- ASP style tags
- Byte-shifted code injection
- Anything that has `<script language="php"></script>`

This last portion - `<script language="php"></script>` - is very important since it is not being used today (and we're better off without it) but as far as I remember it is still supported by the PHP interpreter. So anything between that HTML script tag will be interpreted as PHP. **[All this is very well explained here](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2010/07/php-security-tip-beware-the-opening-tags/).**

What the hell is **Byte-shifted code injection**?

It's kinda hard to explain but the basic idea is it is **obfuscated code injection**. So if an attacker somehow is able to inject  some PHP code and he/she does not want the maintainer/developer to immediately identify it he could do something like the folowing:

```
$smth = 'rpub "lbh ner nggnpxrq naq lbhe jrofvgr unf orra gnxra bire";';
eval(str_rot13($smth));
```

The idea is that the "blob of a sting" is a php code string but byte shifted so it is obfuscated. In my example the `eval()` will receive 
`echo "you are attacked and your website has been taken over"`.
I am using [str_rot13()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php) as it is easy to obfuscate a string back and forward, but this could be a custom function based on [`chr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) or [`ord()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) or any other string manipulation functions.

The best way to prevent such an attack is to prevent `eval()` execution. You should be able to do this through the [`disable_functions` ini directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions). Parse your code of course! But also disable `eval()`.

This type of attack can be really hard to notice with systems like Wordpress, which store a lot of stuff in the DB, most of them unnecessarily. I've personally seen such code injection done to websites (not those I maintained :D) in one of two ways:

- DB corruption (Possible when the application stores something that gets interpreted)
- Direct PHP source file corruption - This is much easier to analyze - just `diff` it against the latest version in a repository or compare it to some source backUp (again via `diff`).

Hope this helped. 
So please start adhering to the [PSR Standards](http://www.php-fig.org/).

- Do not use short tags except for the echo tag `<?=`
- Disable ASP-style tags
- Watch out for code injections.

Comment: "<script language="php"></script>" What?! How did I not know about that syntax after more than 10 years of coding PHP? I need to go check if I've got unknown security flaws now... Ugh.

Comment: Yup, sadly this old feature should be there. I actually need to verify this for 5.5. I will check. but I don't remember it being removed.

Comment: +1 for the perfect detailed explanation, just a small typo in the last word that bothers :)

Comment: Very Well said Answer. Helping a lot for keep vigilant