# <? and <?php both fail, what should work?

Tags: php, apache, php-5.5, apache2.4

running php5.5.9 on apache2.4 under ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server x86_64 my old php code has `<?` in the middle to switch from HTML back to php but it no longer works and the `<?` is just output as if it were HTML.  if i change it to `<?php` then the whole page goes blank. curl shows in this case that the server outputs nothing.  this is where i am trying to output the client IP address.

the web page: http://linuxhomepage.com/
or: http://linuxhomepage.com/index.php

you can see the raw php code here: http://linuxhomepage.com/index.txt

if you get an IPv6 address these won't work as apache is not letting me bind it, yet (i am still digging into that at a lower priority).

`<?` and `<?php` both fail in different ways.  so **how can i make this work?**

*Edit:
IPv6 is working on Apache now, next to get DNS on IPv6.*

Comment: sounds like you might not have `mod_php` enabled?

Comment: php is basically working ... how would it work if  `mod_php` were not?

Comment: have you checked your apache error_log ?

Comment: good answers ... i tried the one i saw first and it worked.  the others might have as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simillar question: [PHP 5.5 short_open_tag=on Security Hole?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554753/php-5-5-short-open-tag-on-security-hole)

You should change short open tag in your php ini to:
`short_open_tag=on`

Comment: this works ... now to figure out why `<?php` does not

Answer (score 4):

`<?` is probably failing because that's being deprecated.

`<?php` probably isn't failing but there's probably an error somewhere in your code and error reporting is turned off on your server, so you just get a blank screen.

To make sure this is the case try something simple like:

```
<?php 
    echo 'test';
?>
```

And make sure that works.

Comment: that works at http://test.linuxhomepage.com/ ... so next to figure out why my old code does not work with `<?php` but does with `<?` under PHP5.5.9 ... first guess is that `<?` engages a compatibility mode.  logs enabled (i think).  gotta look for the logs.

Answer (score 2):

**the `<?` is just output as if it were HTML.**

it's because short_tags are not recommend and disabled by default

- see http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

> PHP also allows for short open tag `<?` (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).

**if i change it to `<?php` then the whole page goes blank.**

it's probably because you have errors in your PHP page (especially if you run old code in new PHP version)

please enable error reporting - php.ini directives `error_reporting` and `display_errors`

- see http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: i changed `short_open_tag` to `on` and the page works ... maybe a more complex error?

Comment: @Skaperen first of all enable error reporting. without it no one will be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Please try deleting the part that is causing the problem.

As of your textfile it would be

```
<?
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
?>
```

If it works without try adding

```
<?php echo "TEST"; ?>
```

If this also works you can replace `"TEST"` by `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and see if it works.