# Warning : illegal string offset

Tags: php, mysql

I asked a question yesterday about a problem with PHP on deleting a row from SQL, using dropdown buttons IDs : [Adding and accessing buttons IDs in a PHP-generated table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885446/adding-and-accessing-buttons-ids-in-a-php-generated-table)

I managed to correct some errors, use a for each instead of a while, ...
But now I have different problems : "Warning illegal string offset" and probably others I'm not aware of.

Here's the code : (problems are below)

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","icare","icare1");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM magasin");
echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Adresse IP</th>
      <th>Adresse ADS</th>
      <th>Région</th>
      <th>Adresse</th>
      <th>Nom du directeur</th>
      <th>Mail</th>
      <th>Téléphone</th>
      <th>GTC</th>
      <th>Date d'installation</th>
  </tr>";
// PROBLEMS START HERE
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<table>
<?php foreach ($data as $key => $row):?>
<tr>
 <td>
    <div class='dropdown-content'>
      <button class='dropbtn'>▶</button>
          <a href="delete.php?Code='<?php echo $row['Code']?>'">Supprimer</a>
    </div>
 </td>
 <?php
 $dat=array('AdresseIP' => $row['AdresseIP'], 'AdresseADS' => $row['AdresseADS'], 'Region' => $row['Region'],
 'Adresse' => $row['Adresse'], 'NomDirecteur' => $row['NomDirecteur'], 'Mail' => $row['Mail'], 'Tel' => $row['Tel'],
 'Gtc' => $row['Gtc'], 'DateInstall' => $row['DateInstall']);
 ?>
 <td><div><?php echo $dat('AdresseIP');?></div></td>
 <td><div><?php echo $dat('AdresseADS');?></div></td>
 <td><div><?php echo $dat('Region');?></div></td>
 <td><div><?php echo $dat('Adresse');?></div></td>
 <td><div><?php echo $dat('NomDirecteur');?></div></td>
 <td><div><?php echo $dat('Mail');?></div></td>
 <td><div><?php echo $dat('Tel');?></div></td>
 <td><div><?php echo $dat('Gtc');?></div></td>
 <td><div><?php echo $dat('DateInstall');?></td>
</tr>
 <?php endforeach ?>
</table>

<?mysqli_close($con);?>
```

I get data from the database, store them in $result, then $data.
Then for each row of $data, I display data in my table cells, starting with a dropdown button.
This dropdown menu redirects to a "Delete" PHP script, which deletes the row linked to the dropdown button.

I get the illegal string offset error and I don't know why...

Also, this line doesn't seem to work because it prints '  1'">Supprimer  '

```
<a href="delete.php?Code='<?php echo $row['Code']?>'">Supprimer</a>
```

I'm kind of lost here and being new into PHP doesn't really help.

Comment: First of all, remove the single quotes in that anchor: `<a href="delete.php?Code=<?php echo $row['Code']?>">`. Note after `Code` are not single quotes `'`. Second, which line throws the `Illegal string offset` error? It is produced by an inexistent key in array maybe.

Comment: This is because you're trying to loop around a row, when you're expecting to be looking around a rowset. Instead of the `$data = ` line and the `foreach` line, you probably want something like `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: You have no error checking at all. How do you know your connection and query succeeded?

Comment: Not convinced this is marked as a relevant duplicate. The error message matches, but the answers don't help with what caused it in this case.

Comment: First of all : i get this illegal string error for each time i try to echo my data in my cells (AdresseIP, AdresseADS,Region,...)

I'm a bit lost because, i've been told to use a foreach instead of a while.
I'll try the while again then.

Comment: About the connection state, i know this works because this is a modification on a code that worked fine before.
I don't think this comes from a failed connection or query.

I looked for similars questions but didn't find any answers, so ...

Comment: @Flumble_ A foreach would only work if you retrieved all rows, but using `mysqli_fetch_array` only fetches one at a time.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
As you said, the while worked perfectly !