# CSS Animation + Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This code might be complete nonsense, but I think you get the idea.

http://pastebin.com/cfsjYnsa (Sorry couldn't format text properly)

So basically I want giveaway.php to run giveaway.html if it exists and then reload page (container) after 30 seconds. If it doesn't exist, reload after 5 seconds.
The idea is I'll delete giveaway.html between those 5~30 seconds so it won't run again after it's done.

Do take in mind I'm bad at web programing, and I'm trying to help a friend; so try not to make it too complicated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you delete giveaway.html??

Comment: Please include the code here as well.

Comment: I do delete giveaway.html because it will change its content as I wish (with an IRC bot). http://pastebin.com/9QPWkSKm (giveaway.html)

Comment: This is supposed to be a code for a streamer. I'm not sure if you're familiar with it but there's a plugin to OBS which checks a page (CLR). So my idea is he checks giveaway.php which will reload every 5 seconds until giveaway.html exists. If it exists, giveaway.html will popup on stream once and then return to its blank status.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731810/if-else-embedding-inside-html) question should help you.