# PHP $_POST not updating

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code (full page: cust_edit.php):

```
<?
session_start(); 
ob_start();
include "../sql.php";
if (!$_SESSION['username']) {
    @include "login.php";
} else {
@include "top.php";
?>

<?
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE custs SET name='$name', date='$date', text='$text' WHERE id='$id'");
    echo '<p align="center"><b>Updated</b></p>';
}

$gid = $id;

if (!isset($gid)) { 
    $gid = addslashes($_GET['id']); 
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM custs WHERE id='$gid'");
$x = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo '
    <br />
    <form name="f" action="cust_edit.php?id='.$x['id'].'" method="post">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="70%" id="submitright">
                    <input value="'.$x['name'].'" type="text" name="name" size="30" maxlength="50">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="70%" id="submitright">
                    <input value="'.$x['date'].'" type="text" name="date" size="30" maxlength="50">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="submitright">
                    <textarea class="ckeditor" name="text" dir="rtl" cols="80" style="width: 70%">'.$x['text'].'</textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="70%" id="submitright">
                    <input type="submit" value="Update">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$gid.'">
    </form>';
}
?>
<?
@include "bottom.php";
?>
```

my problem is that when i'm running this script - and updating the page - the pages is showing up normally and the details shown up in the inputs - but when i click the "Update" button, nothing happens - the page is refreshing but the lines:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE custs SET name='$name', date='$date', text='$text' WHERE id='$id'");
echo '<p align="center"><b>Updated</b></p>';
```

are not running for some reason, can someone help me with that?

Comment: Add name="submit" to <input type="submit" value="Update">

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="submit" value="Update">
```

replace with

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
```

Answer (score 1):

[Please, don't use mysql_* functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated.](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about *[prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)* instead, and use **[PDO](http://php.net/pdo)** or **[MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)** - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose **[PDO](http://php.net/pdo)**, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

And also as others have mentioned don't use [php short open tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). It will not support since PHP 5.4 and onward. Most of time it has discussed here also, [php short_open_tag problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561423/php-short-open-tag-problem)

Answer (score 0):

1. Some webservers will not accept `<?`. Use `<?php` instead.
2. Use mysqli ([MySQL Improved Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)) instead of mysql
3. Your submit don't have `name` attribute `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">`. OR....

You can replace this line:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

on this

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
```